# Storing HTTP Response in order

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm working with an API that takes a while to respond so I thought about storing results for it in an array, essentially caching the response. The problem being that when subscribing, responses are all out of order because it's asynchronous. I first pass data into my observable which then responds accordingly so it's important to know what data was passed that corresponds to the response.

```
this.data[this.i].id
```

The array has all the information but it's all out of order and I don't know what response I'm pulling up exactly.

I use a for loop as such

```
    this.jsonStored = [];
    for (this.i in this.data) {
      this.time.getPunchDataWeek(this.data[this.i].id).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.jsonStored.push(response);
        },
        err => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      );
    }
```

Is there an easy way to keep all my responses pushing to my array in order?

Comment: Do you have access to the backend? If you do maybe you can send the response in order. like `SELECT * FROM users order by id DESC/ASC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) to accomplish this. This operator takes a list of observables and only emits if all of them have emitted a value. The resulting array is in the same order as your observables were when you called it.
You could use it as follows:

```
const observables = this.data.map(data => this.time.getPunchDataWeek(data.id));
forkJoin(...observables).subscribe(results => this.jsonStored.push(...results))
```

Comment: This worked! I'm having trouble accessing jsonStored though. I can't access it like an array anymore. Any idea what's going on? jsonStored[0] logs as undefined.

Comment: are you trying to access jsonStored before your forkJoin observable emits any values?

Comment: ...yes. Sorry and thank you. I logged it under the complete callback method and I can see what is there.